# scanf() is crashing my program upon reading a third dereferenced integer. How can I fix this?

Tags: c, variables, segmentation-fault, crash, scanf

Okay so here is the relevant code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int *v1, *v2, *v3;
    printf("Enter three integers: ");
    scanf("%d %d %d", v1, v2, v3);
    printf("We made it this far?\n");
    /* Other stuff after */
    return 0;
}
```

When an input of any three integers is used, it will successfully allocate those values to `*v1`, `*v2`, but the program will time out when attempting to assign the third integer to `v3`. This also occurs when I give more than three integers. I have segmented the program and scanned for integers one by one, in this process:K */

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int *v1;
    int *v2;
    int *v3;
    printf("Enter three integers: ");
    scanf("%d ", v1);
    printf("%d\n", *v1);
    scanf("%d ", v2);
    printf("%d\n", *v2);
    scanf("%d\n", v3);
    printf("%d\n", *v3);
    printf("We made it this far?\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I really cannot see what the issue is. The format specifiers seem fine, the problem is there no matter the variable name, the input, or anything else. I'm running on VSCode, and not once have we made it to the debug print "We made it this far?" Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `v1`, `v2` and `v3` are pointing nowhere, that yields undefined behaviour. Just declare them as `int v1, v2, v3;` and call `scanf("%d", &v1)`, etc

Comment: *I really cannot see what the issue is.* C is not learned with trials and random attempts of getting a code compiled. Read manuals and books, good manuals and books have good examples. [scanf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: "it will successfully allocate those values " nope it will not.

Comment: Didn't your compiler show you some warning about using variables without assigning a value first? Don't ignore warnings.

Answer (score 4):

Your code has undefined behavior: in `scanf("%d %d %d", v1, v2, v3);` you pass 3 uninitialized pointers as the destinations for the converted integers.  `scanf()` will read the standard input and convert the digits as integers (in base 10) and store the converted values as if by `*v1 = value`. Writing to `*v1` only makes sense if `v1` has been initialized with the address of a valid `int` variable.

The reason your code crashes only for the third variable is pure chance: it seems the initial values of `v1` and `v2` happened to be valid addresses and `scanf` stored the values read from `stdin` to those addresses without crashing with a segmentation fault. Yet *valid addresses* does not say what these pointers pointed to, it can be anywhere in writable memory, including places holding valuable information which modification will cause dire consequences later, even after the program completes. Undefined behavior may not result in immediate obvious consequences, which makes debugging more difficult.

C programmers should use every help available to try and avoid undefined behavior. In this case, compiling with advanced warnings (eg: **gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror**) would have caught the problem as you pass the values of uninitialized variables to `scanf()`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i1, i2, i3;
    int *v1 = &i1, *v2 = &i2, *v3 = &i3;
    printf("Enter three integers: ");
    int n = scanf("%d %d %d", v1, v2, v3);
    if (n == 3) {
        printf("We made it this far?\n");
        /* Other stuff after */
        printf("%d %d %d\n", i1, i2, i3);
    } else {
        printf("scanf returned %d\n", n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that it is idiomatic to pass the addresses of the destination variables to `scanf()` directly instead of using pointer variables. You can remove the definitions of `v1`, `v2` and `v3` and write:

```
    int n = scanf("%d %d %d", &i1, &i2, &i3);
```

It is also important to always check the return value of `scanf()` to detect invalid or missing input.  If `scanf()` fails to convert a value according to the format string, it stops reading the input stream and leaves the offending byte pending in the stream buffer, leaves the destination variables it has not converted yet unmodified (in this case still uninitialized), and returns the number of successful conversions performed and stored or `EOF` if no input was available at all.

Uninitialized variables defined at the local scope of a function with automatic storage (as opposed to `static` storage), have whatever initial value the stack memory or register has when the function enters their scope of definition. These bytes may differ from one run to another, one invocation to another, one machine to another... It is pure chance (and lack of luck) if they form a valid address.

Answer (score 1):

The below code approaches as int to pointer. Program match with int variable's address to pointer. Then When you edit int variable, you can see on the related pointer. I hope that help you as another way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int v1;
    int v2;
    int v3;
    int *p1 = &v1;
    int *p2 = &v2;
    int *p3 = &v3;
    printf ("Enter three integers: ");
    scanf ("%d", &v1);
    printf ("%d\n", *p1);
    scanf ("%d", &v2);
    printf ("%d\n", *p2);
    scanf ("%d", &v3);
    printf ("%d\n", *p3);
    printf ("We made it this far?\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not use `p1` etc in the `scanf()` statements?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler using p1 in scanf is also welcome. Many ways to show "how to". I thought that who asked the question will get understand the relation with more detail.